# How to Parse External JSON code in Greasemonkey and use comparison operators?

Tags: json, greasemonkey

I want to parse this JSON feed https://api.mintpal.com/v1/market/trades/bc/BTC and then execute an alert() when new instances of "total" in the JSON feed are greater than e.g. 100. What's the simplest way to do this? This is the code I have so far.

The essence of what I'm trying to do, ideally I want it to play a sound file and send me email as well since I know executing external macros from the browser is impossible:

```
 $.getJSON('https://api.mintpal.com/v1/market/trades/bc/btc', {}, function(JsonData){

    if ( total >= 10 ) {
      alert(A trade with a value over 10 BTC has been executed.)
    }

// some code to reload the feed to check for new data every 60 seconds.
```

The full thing:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Mintpal1
// @namespace   MintPal
// @include     https://api.mintpal.com/v1/market/trades/bc/btc
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

var $;

// Add jQuery
    (function(){
        if (typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery == 'undefined') {
            var GM_Head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.documentElement,
                GM_JQ = document.createElement('script');

            GM_JQ.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js';
            GM_JQ.type = 'text/javascript';
            GM_JQ.async = true;

            GM_Head.insertBefore(GM_JQ, GM_Head.firstChild);
        }
        GM_wait();
    })();

// Check if jQuery's loaded
    function GM_wait() {
        if (typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery == 'undefined') {
            window.setTimeout(GM_wait, 100);
        } else {
            $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery.noConflict(true);
            letsJQuery();
        }
    }

// All your GM code must be inside this function
    function letsJQuery() {
        alert($); // check if the dollar (jquery) function works
        alert($().jquery); // check jQuery version
    }

$.getJSON('https://api.mintpal.com/v1/market/trades/bc/btc', {}, function(JsonData){

    if ( total >= 10 ) {
      alert(A trade with a value over 10 BTC has been executed.)
    }


  }

});

<script>
     var time = new Date().getTime();
     $(document.body).bind("mousemove keypress", function(e) {
         time = new Date().getTime();
     });

     function refresh() {
         if(new Date().getTime() - time >= 60000) 
             window.location.reload(true);
         else 
             setTimeout(refresh, 10000);
     }

     setTimeout(refresh, 10000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using $.getJSON you won't have to parse the JSON response, it will be done automatically.

But the resulting JSON includes an array of `trades`. You'll have to loop through this array and execute the alert (or whatever code you want) if the `total` property of one of the trades is greater than 100

```
$.getJSON('https://api.mintpal.com/v1/market/trades/bc/btc', {}, function(JsonData){
    var trades = JsonData.trades;
    for(i=0, max=trades.length; i<max; i++) {
       if ( trades[i].total >= 100 ) {
         alert("A trade with a value over 100 BTC has been executed.")
       }
    }

});
```